# How can I use image_tag in a javascript response?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to realize following:

```
$(".share-icon").html("<%= image_tag(@card.photo.url(:small)) %>");
```

This is obviously not working but how can I use `image_tag`in a JS response?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `.erb` to the file so it's name follows the pattern `foo.js.erb` and then rails will interpret the `<%...%>` section for you.

Comment: `$(".share-icon").html("<%= j image_tag(@card.photo.url(:small)) %>");` will work..

Comment: Thanks Arup, `j`or `escape_javascript` did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try escaping the html generated by `image_tag` using `escape_javascript`

```
$(".share-icon").html("<%= escape_javascript image_tag(@card.photo.url(:small)) %>");
```